# How to play a SoundPool with a MediaPlayer at the same time?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to play the SoundPools with a MediaPlayer at the same time with a button press and every time I played the SoundPools when the MediaPlayer is playing, it doesn't play. Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MediaPlayer gbTheme;
    SoundPool stop;
    SoundPool loop;
    int sirenLoop;
    int sirenStop;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        stop = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        sirenStop = stop.load(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.ecto_siren_stop, 1);
        gbTheme = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ghostbusters_theme);
        loop = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        sirenLoop = loop.load(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.ecto_siren_time_loopable, 1);
        Button on = (Button)findViewById(R.id.turnOnButton);
        on.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sirenLoop = loop.play(sirenLoop, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1);
            }
        });
        Button off = (Button)findViewById(R.id.turnOffButton);
        off.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loop.stop(sirenLoop);
                sirenStop = stop.play(sirenStop, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
            }
        });
        Button play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.playButton);
        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                gbTheme.start();
                gbTheme.setLooping(true);
            }
        });
        Button stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stopButton);
        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                gbTheme.pause();
                gbTheme.seekTo(0);
            }
        });
```

What I am trying to do is play both sounds at the same time when the 'Turn On' or 'Turn Off' buttons are pressed when MediaPlayer is already playing.

Comment: I think that you need to debug it and see what is not being set correctly e.g. what is the value of `sirenStop = stop.load`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the problem is that you are using "stop" for both the SoundPool object and the Button object.
try this one and let me know if it work or not .

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
MediaPlayer gbTheme;
SoundPool stop;
SoundPool loop;
int sirenLoop;
int sirenStop;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    stop = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    sirenStop = stop.load(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.ecto_siren_stop, 1);
    gbTheme = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ghostbusters_theme);
    loop = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    sirenLoop = loop.load(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.ecto_siren_time_loopable, 1);
    Button on = (Button)findViewById(R.id.turnOnButton);
    on.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sirenLoop = loop.play(sirenLoop, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1);
        }
    });
    Button off = (Button)findViewById(R.id.turnOffButton);
    off.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            loop.stop(sirenLoop);
            sirenStop = stop.play(sirenStop, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
        }
    });
    Button play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.playButton);
    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            gbTheme.start();
            gbTheme.setLooping(true);
        }
    });
    Button stopButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stopButton);
    stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            gbTheme.pause();
            gbTheme.seekTo(0);
        }
    });
}
```

}

and if that does not works try to use different audio stream for the SoundPools.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
MediaPlayer gbTheme;
SoundPool stop;
SoundPool loop;
int sirenLoop;
int sirenStop;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    stop = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    sirenStop = stop.load(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.ecto_siren_stop, 1);
    gbTheme = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ghostbusters_theme);
    loop = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, 0); // Use STREAM_ALARM for SoundPools
    sirenLoop = loop.load(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.ecto_siren_time_loopable, 1);
    Button on = (Button)findViewById(R.id.turnOnButton);
    on.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sirenLoop = loop.play(sirenLoop, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1);
        }
    });
    Button off = (Button)findViewById(R.id.turnOffButton);
    off.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            loop.stop(sirenLoop);
            sirenStop = stop.play(sirenStop, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
        }
    });
    Button play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.playButton);
    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            gbTheme.start();
            gbTheme.setLooping(true);
        }
    });
    Button stopButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stopButton);
    stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            gbTheme.pause();
            gbTheme.seekTo(0);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Also, do you know why my SoundPools stops playing after a while when I press the buttons?

Comment: i will look into it , meanwhile try it and if it works let me know :)

Comment: It worked, I changed my SoundPool button and it plays :)

Comment: good to know that ;)

Comment: Just checking if you found anything about my other problem